# access levels of a tree implemented as nested list

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree

I implemented this tree as a nested list:

```
 1
/ \
2  3
  / \
 4   5

> tree <- list(1, list(2), list(3, list(4), list(5)))

> data.tree::FromListSimple(tree, nodeName = "1")
  levelName
1 1        
2  ¦--1    
3  °--2    
4      ¦--1
5      °--2
```

How can I extract the levels of the tree, in this example that would

1st level: [1]
2nd level: [2,3]
3rd level: [4,5]

`tree[[1]]` is the first level, that's easy.
But `tree[[2]]` is only `2`.

So the second level would be `c(tree[[2]], tree[[3]][1])`

How can I generalize this to any tree structure represented as a nested list?

Comment: you say nested list, but the way you extract from `tree` does not look like a simple regular nested list. can you show how you constructed `tree`?

Comment: @RolandASc sorry, I forgot to copy this line. I added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain `base` R, you could do this with a recursive function (as long as your `tree` isn't too huge). For example:

```
getElems <- function(tree, depth, level) {
  if (depth == level) {
    if (is.list(tree)) 
      tree[[1]]
  } else {
    sapply(tree, getElems, depth = depth + 1, level = level)
  }
}

# first level
unlist(getElems(tree, 1, 1))
# second level (always starting the search from depth = 1)
unlist(getElems(tree, 1, 2))
# third level
unlist(getElems(tree, 1, 3))
```